# How can i make a jquery script NOT run until the visible part of it is loaded? (actually on the screen of the user)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

So, i've been looking all day and havent found anything quite like what i'm looking for. Im making one of those number-counting advertise thingies on websites that numbers roll from 0 to (lets say) 100 and below it says "customer satisfaction" because that looks good imo. though, once the website is loaded, the script starts even if the counter isnt visible, so when you scroll down to it its already finished. How will i make it not run untill its loaded in the screen?
Code so far:

---

**HTML**

```html
<!-- jQuery number counter - animated -->
<div class="container-fluid padding">
<div class="row padding">
    <div class="counter col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 countr-box">
      <h2 class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="98" data-speed="1500"></h2>
      <p class="count-text ">TEXT!!</p>
    </div>
        <div class="counter col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 countr-box">
      <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="logoo"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="counter col-sm-12 col-md-4 countr-box">
      <h2 class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="100" data-speed="1500"></h2>
      <p class="count-text ">o <strong>yeet</strong> sample-text</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.col_half { width: 49%; }
.col_third { width: 32%; }
.col_fourth { width: 23.5%; }
.col_fifth { width: 18.4%; }
.col_sixth { width: 15%; }
.col_three_fourth { width: 74.5%;}
.col_twothird{ width: 66%;}
.col_half,
.col_third,
.col_twothird,
.col_fourth,
.col_three_fourth,
.col_fifth{
    position: relative;
    display:inline;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.end { margin-right: 0 !important; }
/* Column Grids End */

.wrapper { width: 980px; margin: 30px auto; position: relative;}
.counter { background-color: #ffffff; padding: 20px 0; border-radius: 5px;}
.count-title { font-size: 40px; font-weight: normal;  margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 0; text-align: center; }
.count-text { font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal;  margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 0; text-align: center; }
.fa-2x { margin: 0 auto; float: none; display: table; color: #4ad1e5; }

.countr-box{
  padding: 25px;
  font-family: serif;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

**javascript**

```js
$(function ($) {
    $.fn.countTo = function (options) {
        options = options || {};

        return $(this).each(function () {
            // set options for current element
            var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, {
                from:            $(this).data('from'),
                to:              $(this).data('to'),
                speed:           $(this).data('speed'),
                refreshInterval: $(this).data('refresh-interval'),
                decimals:        $(this).data('decimals')
            }, options);

            // how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update
            var loops = Math.ceil(settings.speed / settings.refreshInterval),
                increment = (settings.to - settings.from) / loops;

            // references & variables that will change with each update
            var self = this,
                $self = $(this),
                loopCount = 0,
                value = settings.from,
                data = $self.data('countTo') || {};

            $self.data('countTo', data);

            // if an existing interval can be found, clear it first
            if (data.interval) {
                clearInterval(data.interval);
            }
            data.interval = setInterval(updateTimer, settings.refreshInterval);

            // initialize the element with the starting value
            render(value);

            function updateTimer() {
                value += increment;
                loopCount++;

                render(value);

                if (typeof(settings.onUpdate) == 'function') {
                    settings.onUpdate.call(self, value);
                }

                if (loopCount >= loops) {
                    // remove the interval
                    $self.removeData('countTo');
                    clearInterval(data.interval);
                    value = settings.to;

                    if (typeof(settings.onComplete) == 'function') {
                        settings.onComplete.call(self, value);
                    }
                }
            }

            function render(value) {
                var formattedValue = settings.formatter.call(self, value, settings);
                $self.html(formattedValue);
            }
        });
    };

    $.fn.countTo.defaults = {
        from: 0,               // the number the element should start at
        to: 0,                 // the number the element should end at
        speed: 1000,           // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
        refreshInterval: 100,  // how often the element should be updated
        decimals: 0,           // the number of decimal places to show
        formatter: formatter,  // handler for formatting the value before rendering
        onUpdate: null,        // callback method for every time the element is updated
        onComplete: null       // callback method for when the element finishes updating
    };

    function formatter(value, settings) {
        return value.toFixed(settings.decimals);
    }
}(jQuery));

jQuery(function ($) {
  // custom formatting example
  $('.count-number').data('countToOptions', {
    formatter: function (value, options) {
      return value.toFixed(options.decimals).replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
    }
  });

  // start all the timers
  $('.timer').each(count);

  function count(options) {
    var $this = $(this);
    options = $.extend({}, options || {}, $this.data('countToOptions') || {});
    $this.countTo(options);
  }
});
```

NOTE, THE JS CODE ISN'T MINE, ITS FROM https://codepen.io/syedrafeeq/pen/rcfsJ

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try implementing the counter method once you scroll down to the div in the window.
You can use something like this:

```
    $(function() {
        var oTop = $('#counter').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
        $(window).scroll(function(){

            var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();
            console.log( pTop + ' - ' + oTop );   //just for your debugging
            if( pTop > oTop ){
                start_counter();
            }
        });
    });

    function start_counter(){
        alert('starting counter');
        //Add your code here
    }
```

Comment: give me some time to look into it, im currently starting to learn js so this is all new to me, ill get back to ya in a bit

Comment: So, if i understand, this code makes 2 new variables that correspond to the bottom of the window and the top of the div containing the counter, and when one gets a higher value than the other the script runs?

Comment: yes. This script would be running once you have successfully scrolled to your div in the browser window. you can put the counting code inside the **start_counter** method.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong but trying to implement your script in my code made the entire counter section disappear, imma check it again once I'm at home tonight.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the level of browser support you need, the intersection observer API might be helpful.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesnt seem to work for IE and some other mobile browsers and while i know that not a lot of people use it, im trying to make the website work on every browser the same so i wont go with this solution unless i have no other choice.